# DotNetNuke DDRMenu : Outputting node not included in menu breadcrumb xslt dnn

Tags: xslt, dotnetnuke, xmlnode, ddrmenu

I am having problems trying to get the following XSLT template for the DotNetNuke DDRMenu to spit out the last page/node of the breadcrumb for the following conditions:

- the last page is NOT "Include(d) in the Menu" in its page settings
- however the last page is a child of the the parent node (which ***does*** show up in my output)

How do I get the page not included in the menu to be outputted at the end of my breadcrumb from the following XSL template?:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html"/>
    <xsl:param name="separator"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="root" />
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="root">
        <ul>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="//node[@breadcrumb=1]" />
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="node">
        <li>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@enabled = 1">
                    <a href="{@url}" title="{@title}">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@text" />
                    </a>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="@text" />
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </li>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found out that my XSLT code is fine.

The problem was that my ascx skin object tag was missing an attribute setting to allow hidden pages to be output. Adding **IncludeHidden="true"** to the skin object tag fixed the problem.

Example below:

```
<ddr:MENU MenuStyle="breadcrumb" IncludeHidden="true" runat="server" />
```

[This resource](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/DDRMenu-reference-guide.aspx#IncludeHidden_5) (http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/DDRMenu-reference-guide.aspx#IncludeHidden_5) says:

> **IncludeHidden**
>
> For DotNetNuke 6 only, if set to "true", hidden pages will be included. This can be useful for creating separate menus to show site sections that are hidden from the main menu.